A barrier differential inequality implies a distributional differential inequality
I encountered the following statement while reading an article about Ricci flow:

Thus $\Delta d_{K, p}^2\leq4$ in the barrier sense, hence in the viscosity sense and in the distributional sense.

I couldn't find the definition for viscosity sense while searching for references. The definitions of barrier sense and distributional sense are as follows:

Given $f\in C(M)$ and a function $g$ on $M$, one says that $\Delta f \leq g$ in the sense of barriers if for all $q\in M$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $q$ and some $f_\epsilon \in C^2(V)$ so that $f_\epsilon(q) = f(q)$, $f_\epsilon \geq f$ on $V$ and $\Delta f_\epsilon \leq g+\epsilon$ on $V$.


The other sense of a differential inequality is the distributional sense, i.e. $\Delta f ≤ g$ if for every nonnegative compactly-supported smooth function $\phi$ on $M$,
$$\int_M(\Delta \phi)f~dV \leq \int_M \phi g~dV.$$

I tried to directly use the definition of barrier sense to obtain distributional sense. But I found I need a uniform convergence:
$$\Delta f\leq g {\rm ~in~the~barrier~sense}\implies\Delta f_\epsilon\leq g+\epsilon$$
$$\implies\int_M(\Delta \phi)f_\epsilon~dV \leq \int_M \phi (g+\epsilon)~dV\overset{\rm uniform~convergence}\implies\int_M(\Delta \phi)f~dV \leq \int_M \phi g~dV$$
$$\implies\Delta f\leq g {\rm ~in~the~distributional~sense}.$$
Then I don't know what to do else. Any help would be appreciated!

The definition of viscosity solution is as follows:

For a continuous function $f$ on $M$, we say $\Delta f\leq g$ in the viscosity sense, if for any $q\in M$, $\Delta\phi(q) ≤ g$ whenever $\phi \in C^2(U)$ and $\displaystyle(f−\phi)(q) = \inf_U~(f−\phi)$, where $U$ is a neighborhood of $q$.

Clearly "barrier" implies "viscosity". Indeed, assume $\Delta f\leq g$ in the barrier sense and $\phi \in C^2(U)$ satisfies $\displaystyle(f−\phi)(q) = \inf_U~(f−\phi)$. For all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $q$ and some $f_\epsilon \in C^2(U)$ so that $f_\epsilon(q) = f(q)$, $f_\epsilon \geq f$ on $U$ and $\Delta f_\epsilon \leq g+\epsilon$ on $U$. Then $f_\epsilon-\phi\geq f-\phi$, and
$$(f_\epsilon-\phi)(q)=(f-\phi)(q)=\inf_U~(f−\phi)\leq\inf_U~(f_\epsilon−\phi),$$
which means
$$(f_\epsilon-\phi)(q)=\inf_U~(f_\epsilon−\phi),$$
so
$$\Delta(f_\epsilon-\phi)(q)\geq0$$
in the classic sense. Therefore
$$\Delta\phi(q)\leq\Delta f_\epsilon(q)\leq g+\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this proves our claim.

The relationship between "viscosity" and "distributional" can be found in the paper

Hitoshi Ishii. On the equivalence of two notions of weak solutions, viscosity solutions and distribution solutions. Funkcial. Ekvac., 38(1):101–120, 1995.

